# Is the topological index of a self-adjoint operator always zero?

Tags: topology, topological-order, topological-phase

By the Atiyah-Singer index theorem, the index of a self-adjoint opeartor D (e.g., Hamiltonian) is given by

Index(D) = dim Ker(D) − dim Ker(D*),

where D* is the adjoint operator of D. Since D is self-adjoint, D=D*, we conclude that Index(D)=0. Is this conclusion right? Can we define a non-zero index for the self-adjoint operator?

Answer (score 1):

Your conclusion is right. The index defined in the way you did, of course, can not be non-zero for self-adjoint operator. One can try to define some other index, if one wants, but I am afraid that it would have nothing to do with the Atiyah-Singer theorem.

Answer (score 1):

There are unfortunately two conflicting definitions of ${\rm Index}(D)$, and although your conclusion (that the index of a self-adjoint operator vanishes) is [correct](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2174424) for the definition you gave, in particular in the context of the Atiyah-Singer index theorem people [tend](https://mathoverflow.net/q/363388) [to](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/150253/atiyah-singer-for-pseudodifferential-operators-via-heat-kernel?rq=1) [talk](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Eerabin/McKean%20Singer%20Talk.pdf) about the ''index of a self-adjoint operator'', while in fact they mean a nonzero number defined as follows.

Assume that the Hilbert space splits into two parts $\mathcal H=\mathcal H_+\oplus \mathcal H_-$ which the self-adjoint operator $D$ interchanges. To be precise, for dense subspaces $\mathcal H'_+=\mathcal H_+\cap{\rm dom} D$ and $\mathcal H'_-=\mathcal H_-\cap{\rm dom} D$, we assume that
$$D(\mathcal H'_+)\subseteq\mathcal H_-,\qquad D(\mathcal H'_-)\subseteq\mathcal H_+.$$
In this case, we define $D_+:=D_{|\mathcal H'_+}:\mathcal H'_+\to \mathcal H_-$ and $D_-:=D_{|\mathcal H'_-}:\mathcal H'_-\to \mathcal H_+$. It is most consistent with Fredholm theory to define
$${\rm Index}(D_+):=\dim \ker D_+-\dim{\rm coker} D_+.$$
What can be confusing is that **many authors refer to ${\rm Index}(D_+)$ as ${\rm Index}(D)$**. There is reasoning behind this, of course, namely that
$${\rm Index}(D_+)=\dim\ker D_+-\dim\ker D_-=-{\rm Index}(D_-)$$
and one can think of ${\rm Index}(D_+)=-{\rm Index}(D_-)$ as something defined just by $D$ and the splitting $\mathcal H=\mathcal H_+\oplus \mathcal H_-$. Indeed, if you associate a grading $\gamma$ to the splitting $\mathcal H=\mathcal H_+\oplus\mathcal H_-$ by defining $\gamma_{|\mathcal H_+}:={\rm id}_{\mathcal H_+}$ and $\gamma_{|\mathcal H_-}:=-{\rm id}_{\mathcal H_-}$ then you can write for instance ${\rm Index}(D_+)={\rm Tr}(\gamma e^{-D^2})$, showing explicitly that ${\rm Index}(D_+)$ depends only on $D$ and $\gamma$. When written out in terms of $D_+$ and $D_-$, this states that
$${\rm Index}(D_+)={\rm Tr}(e^{-D_-D_+})-{\rm Tr}(e^{-D_+D_-}).$$
In physics, $\gamma$ typically is [the gamma matrix $\gamma^5$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices) and $\mathcal H=\mathcal H_+\oplus\mathcal H_-$ is the bundle of (square-integrable) [spinors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinor), split into spinors of [positive and negative chirality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirality_(physics)).